How to make a matrix/chart to be rendered on lowest drill down level while while Y-Axis is updating
I have a matrix and bar chart with two fields parameters as Y-Axis: Retailer and National Retailer
When I updates fields parameter's value matrix rendered collapsed, i.e. on their highest level.
how to make it to be always expanded?                                 .
like below :



Retailer
National Retailer




RETAILER 1
Total



Nat_RETAILER 1


RETAILER 2
Total



Nat_RETAILER 2


RETAILER 3
Total



Nat_RETAILER 3



